# Dynamic query using In with a List with multiple fields

Tags: apex, soql, list, fields, dynamic-soql

I have an array of this class

```
  global with sharing class JiraTimeLog {
    public Long worklogId;
    public String jiraIssue;
    public String milestone;
    public String resource;
    public Date dateWorked;
    public Decimal hours;
    public String notes;
  }
```

that I populated. Now, I'd like to look for records in an sObject that are in the List of objects using specific fields.

Looks like I need to do it this way...

```
@HttpPost
  global static void load(JiraTimeLog[] jiraTimeLogs) {
  List<String> workLogIds = new List<String>();
  List<String> resourceNames = new List<String>();

  for(JiraTimeLog jiraTimeLog: jiraTimeLogs) {
    workLogIds.add(jiraTimeLog.worklogId);
    resourceNames.add(jiraTimeLog.resource);
  }

  List<Timecard__c> timecards = [SELECT Id,<many other fields> FROM Timecard__c WHERE Time_Log__c IN :workLogIds];
  List<Contact> resources = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name IN :resourceNames];

// Then loop through jiraTimeLogs a second time to use the data in timecards and resources
```

Does that look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this type of syntax is only supported for sObjects:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = :accounts];
```

And even then, as you may have guessed, it only supports the Id field. For user classes (ones we create ourselves), you need to extract the values to a new list using code, then bind to that, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there an easy way to create a List from another list like: List<String> foo = jiraTimeLogs.foo or would I just have to loop through to do it?

Comment: You'll need to loop through it @nstuyvesant

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox.